# Kivy screen transition doesn't work, when Matplotlib plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, kivy-language

Transition back to the MainSceen doesn't work, when I plot a histogram using the matplotlib. I am able to switch to the SecondScreen, but the screen looks weird (both screens overlap):
[image]

Clicking on "Go back to the first screen" produces an error: TypeError: Argument 'c' has incorrect type (expected kivy.graphics.instructions.Instruction, got FigureCanvasKivy)

minimal example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            Clock.schedule_once(self.show_hist)

        def show_hist(self, *args):
        
            self.toPlot = random.sample(range(1, 36), 30)
            self.fig = plt.figure()
            self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
            self.ax.set_xlabel('Score', fontsize=30)
            self.ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=30)
            self.ax.set_title('Histogram of scores',fontsize=30)
            plt.xticks(fontsize=30)
            plt.yticks(fontsize=30)
            self.binsize = 36

            self.h = self.ax.hist(self.toPlot, self.binsize)
            self.canvas = self.fig.canvas

            self.hist2show.add_widget(self.canvas)

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


# load kivy file
presentation = Builder.load_file("demo_kivy.kv")

class normApp(App):

    # change color to white
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

    def build(self):   
        return presentation
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    normApp().run()
```

Kivy file:

```
ScreenManagement:

    MainScreen:
        name: "MainScreen"
        id: main_screen

    SecondScreen:
        name: "SecondScreen"
        id: second_screen


<MainScreen>:
    name: "MainScreen"

    hist2show:hist2show

    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        rows:3


        BoxLayout: 
            id: hist2show
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            background_color: 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2

            

        Button: 
            text: "Next screen"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            background_color: 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
            on_release: app.root.current = "SecondScreen"


<SecondScreen>
    name: "SecondScreen"


    Button:
        text: "Go back to the first screen"
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        background_color: 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
        on_release: app.root.current = "MainScreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone has the same issue... the problem disappears after changing

```
self.canvas = self.fig.canvas
self.hist2show.add_widget(self.canvas)
```

to

```
canvas = self.fig.canvas
self.hist2show.add_widget(canvas)
```